# Is there a way to execute a python code sequentially and with an underterminate amount of variables?

Tags: python, variables

I've written a working python code using a predefined variable.

```
variable = "first_variable"

#code

with open(f"{variable}.txt", "w") as w_file:
    w_file.write("Something")
```

I now want to **adapt** the code to accept any number of variables as parameters and process them one after the other.
In the shell, I would like to call it that way:

```
python3 code.py first_variable second_variable third_variable n_variable
```

Any idea on how i could do that? I tried using input, creating a function or with a while loop but failed...

Comment: `argparse` module ?

Comment: Those shell parameters are all stored in `sys.argv`. For more complex scripts the the argparse module can help you setup different options for parsing the shell parameters while auto creating help when `-h` is used -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Since they just want to iterate through all the args and don't have any other switches to support, `argparse` seems like overkill.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I've settled on using the sys module, I'll learn about argparse on another occasion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list of all the arguments passed to `python` (starting with the name of your script).  You can just iterate through each element of it like any other list:

```
import sys

for variable in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(f"{variable}.txt", "w") as w_file:
        w_file.write("Something")
```

Note that `sys.argv[0]` will be `code.py`, which you probably don't want to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is to get command line arguments.
According to [command-line-arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#command-line-arguments), you can obtain it from `sys.argv`, it gives you a list of parameter given by user:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.argv)
['demo.py', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```